# Submitting an api request dynamically with user input

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api

I am trying to submit a search request to the Wikipedia API using a form that is fulled out by the user.  When the form is submitted, however, the page refreshes and nothing is done.  I have tried to "preventDefault", and that did not get the job done.  I will post my html and javascript code below (if my css is somehow helpful, I can of course supply that as well).

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div class="random text-center">
    <a target="_blank" href ="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random">Get a Random Entry</a>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="text-center">
    <form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="search" id="search">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
  </div>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('#search').submit(search());


function search(){

  var value = ("#search").val();
  //var value = "eggs";
  $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=" + value + "&utf8=&format=json&callback=?", function(json) {
  json.query.search.forEach( function(val) {
    var title = val.title;
    var snippet = val.snippet;
    titleURL = title.replace(/ /g, "_");


    $(".results").append("<a target='_blank' href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + titleURL +"'><div class='result'><div class='title'>" + title + "</div><br/><div class='snippet'>" + snippet + "</div></div></a><br/>")

  });

  var title = json.query.search[0].title;
  var snippet = json.query.search[0].snippet;
});

};
});
```

codepen:

http://codepen.io/blarmon/pen/rrZzyB

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: You definitely need to prevent default.

Comment: You should pass in `search` not `search()` as the event handler.